# Why is this character called "Composite Superman" and not "Composite Batman"?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, superman

In DC Comics' strange history, we have the character of Composite Superman:

[image: Composite Superman]

[Robot Chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Chicken_DC_Comics_Special_III:_Magical_Friendship) has a sketch where he shows up and there is an argument about his name:

> Superman: Dear God, it's half a monster!
>
> Batman: He's…he's some sort of—
>
> Superman: —Composite Superman!
>
> Batman: Composite *Batman* you bastard!
>
> Superman: Not if I tell people first!

In the comics where he is introduced, why is he called "Composite Superman" and not "Composite Batman" if he's 50% of both?

Comment: More importantly, how does that half-mask stay on?

Comment: @Tim - Because he's Batman (sorta)

Comment: @Tim It only half stays on.

Comment: A thought occurs... if left half is peak human, but right half is superhuman, then the first time he does anything he's gonna tear himself apart.

Comment: @Tim Well, in Robot Chicken, they defeat him when they realize that only half of his body has "Super Balls". Of course, they needed a kryptonite batarang to defeat the other half.

Comment: @Tim - All of him is superhuman. It's just the costume that's half and half

Comment: @Tim: more importantly, is there a Composite Lois (or a Composite Bruce's many girlfriends?)?

Comment: The question was, I'm sure, asked in jest but I'll give it a serious answer.  The half-mask stays on because, like the rest of the costume it's a creation of his Chameleon Boy-like powers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not entirely clear. Notably, the process by which he gained his powers drove him temporarily insane so his reasoning may be similarly unfathomable.

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[World's Finest Comics Vol 1. #142](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_142)</sup></sub>

That being said, we know that he had a **deep and abiding hatred of Superman** which may account for his decision to name himself thusly.

> [image]

Comment: Interesting. He's definitely obsessed with getting back at Superman, so being a "Composite *Superman*" makes sense. Batman almost seems like an afterthought.

Comment: @Thunderforge That was my thought. Why even use Batman at all? Why not only be a green Superman and call it a day? This looks like it came after Bizarro's first appearance, which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: One should note that he has a whole mess of powers (hence, composite), including Superman's. It's make more sense to call himself the Composite Legionnaire - except, of course, that the Legion wasn't commonly known of (in spite of their statuettes and his experiences with them being covered by this museum). Composite Batman would make no real sense, as Batman has no part directly in his origins or powers. Perhaps the better question would be why the heck did he use Batman's costume as part of his (in-universe - out of universe, being in *WORLD'S FINEST* makes it pretty obvious)?